# What data type does OnFields method in hibernate search accept

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-search

I want to be able to use hibernate search to search only fields chosen by user in form.

For example if user choose to search by first name, hibernate should consider only first name. if user choose first name and last name, hibernate should consider first name and last name.

```
 FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
                org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.
                        getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

        QueryBuilder queryBuilder =
                fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
                        .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Client.class).get();

        org.apache.lucene.search.Query query =
                queryBuilder
                        .keyword()
                        .wildcard()
                        // i want below section (fields) to change based on user input but can't do it with list<string> or collection
                        .onFields("idNumber", "firstName", "middleName","lastName","nationality")
                        .matching("*"+searchText.toLowerCase()+"*")
                        .createQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `List.toArray`:

```
List<String> fieldsSelectedByUser = ...;
 FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
                org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.
                        getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

        QueryBuilder queryBuilder =
                fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
                        .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Client.class).get();

        org.apache.lucene.search.Query query =
                queryBuilder
                        .keyword()
                        .wildcard()
                        .onFields(fieldsSelectedByUser.toArray(new String[0]))
                        .matching("*"+searchText.toLowerCase()+"*")
                        .createQuery();
```